# Does the series $\frac{\arctan(n)}{n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have the series $\sum ^\infty _7 \frac{\arctan(n)}{n}$. Does it converge(absolutely)? I've tried the comparison test because $|\arctan(n)|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, but I can't get further. Because $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\arctan(n)}{n} =0$, it must be convergent, but is it absolutely convergent? And how do you prove that?

Answer (score 1):

You have $${\arctan(n)\over n}\sim {\pi\over 2n}$$
as $n\to\infty$

Comment: yeah but $\frac{\pi}{2n}$ is divergent. So using the comparison test will mean that my series is divergent, but $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{arctan(n)}{n}=0$, which means that it must be convergent

Comment: @Mathematicxcz No; the limit of the terms of the sum must be zero in order to have convergence, but there are examples where the limit is zero and we still have divergence. The harmonic series that you just pointed out is an example. Basically, this problem comes down to showing that $\arctan(n) \geq \pi/4$ for $n \geq 1$ and then comparing to (a multiple of) the harmonic series.

Comment: @Ian you are totally right, I just realised that Thanks!